# RHEL (CentOS, SL) process performance statistics

Tags: centos, web-server, performance, email-server

Is there any way to find out sometimes when the server load is high, what process and what activity cause that ? 
I have a shared webserver and mailserver (HTTP, DNS, SMTP, IMAP, POP, FTP,...) and sometimes the load is very high. 25-50 or more. How can I find out what cause that, and what can I do to give normal performance continuously ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the command "top" or install [htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/) to see what processes are eating the most of the system's capacity.
I could also go into tools like [sysstat](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/documentation.html) (iostat / vmstat / etc.) but using top would be the first thing I'd try.
Since it is a shared server, are you able to control all processes of all users and applications?

Comment: Yes, I know that commands, but they can't provide information what cause the load, and why. I can's see the output of the top all day, systat seems better, but even if I know the load is high, they don't record which process cause the load at that time. A process based statistics could be help, but as I see, this utilities can't do that.

Comment: Answer with the wrong user. It was me.